# How to use regular expression to separate numbers and characters in strings like "30M1000N20M"

Tags: regex, python

I'm trying to separate the `[0-9]` and `[A-Z]` in strings like these:

```
100M
20M1D80M
20M1I79M
20M10000N80M
```

I tried using the Python `re` module, and the following is the code I used:

```
>>>import re
>>>num_alpha = re.compile('(([0-9]+)([A-Z]))+')
>>>str1="100M"
>>>n_a_match = num_alpha.match(str1)
>>>n_a_match.group(2), n_a_match.group(3)

100,M   #just what I want

>>>str1="20M10000N80M"
>>>n_a_match = num_alpha.match(str1)
>>>n_a_match.groups()

('80M', '80', 'M')  #only the last one, how can I get the first two?
#expected result ('20M','20','M','10000N','10000','N','80M','80','M')
```

This regular expression works well for strings which contain only one match, but not several groups of matches. How can I handle that using regular expressions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using `re.findall`. If you intend to iterate over the results, rather than building a list, you could use `re.finditer` instead. Here's an example of how that would work:

```
>>> re.findall("(([0-9]+)([A-Z]))", "20M10000N80M")
[('20M', '20', 'M'), ('10000N', '10000', 'N'), ('80M', '80', 'M')]
```

If you don't want the combined numbers+letters string, you can remove the outer parentheses from the match and just get the separate parts:

```
>>> re.findall("([0-9]+)([A-Z])", "20M10000N80M")
[('20', 'M'), ('10000', 'N'), ('80', 'M')]
```

Or, if you don't want tuples at all (and you don't need to worry about malformed input, such as strings with several letters in a row), you could change the pattern to an alternation, and get the values one by one:

```
>>> re.findall("([0-9]+|[A-Z])", "20M10000N80M")
['20', 'M', '10000', 'N', '80', 'M']
```

Comment: Great. I did not recall thefunction `findall()`. Appreciate the last regular expression.

Comment: All answers are great. If allowed, I would choose all three. I chose this for the second regular expression gives exactly what I want. Again, thanks to all.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the `split` method:

```
>>> str1="20M10000N80M"
>>> num_alpha = re.compile('(([0-9]+)([A-Z]))')
>>> l = num_alpha.split(str1)
>>> l
['', '20M', '20', 'M', '', '10000N', '10000', 'N', '', '80M', '80', 'M', '']
```

Note that I removed the `+` in the regex.

And to remove the empty strings, a list generator:

```
>>> l_without_empty = [x for x in l if x != '']
['20M', '20', 'M', '10000N', '10000', 'N', '80M', '80', 'M']
```

---

Edit:

Or, as said in comments:

```
>>> l_without_empty = [x for x in l if x]
['20M', '20', 'M', '10000N', '10000', 'N', '80M', '80', 'M']
```

Comment: Small comment, you can use `if not x` instead of `x != ''`. Not an issue but just FYI

Comment: Wait, that's not right.  `if not x` here should be `if x`; you want to keep the ones which have `bool(x) == True`.  `if not x` would only keep the ones which *are* empty.

Comment: `''` is `False` and other strings are `True`. Therefore your second list comprehension is keeping the empty strings, *not* the non-empty ones. You probably didn't execute your second list comprehension to test it...

Comment: Corrected the mistake. Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not even know there is a function called `split()` in `re`. Here is clear.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to go for `re.findall` instead:

```
>>> string = "20M10000N80M"
>>> groups = re.findall(r'((\d+)(\D+))', string)
[('20M', '20', 'M'), ('10000N', '10000', 'N'), ('80M', '80', 'M')]
```

So, you can see the different groups returned as tuples, then, if you really want it as a tuple as you present - you can flatten it:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> tuple(chain.from_iterable(groups))
('20M', '20', 'M', '10000N', '10000', 'N', '80M', '80', 'M')
```

Comment: Thanks, very nice. It is my pleasure to learn module `itertools`.

Comment: @ct586 it is a very useful and powerful library - have fun in your learning!